# How to get total members with certain tags on mailchimp API v3.0?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Is there a way to return the total members in a specific list that have a certain tag?

I'm trying to do this without using custom logic outside of the API call.

I can get the member count of a certain list by running: `https://usXX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{ListId}?fields=stats.member_count`, but I'm having trouble getting count's for specific tags within a list.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe this is possible over the API, without building custom logic. The only way to look at tags is, `GET /lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}/tags`. So really you would need to first get the list members, then loop through and look at the tags for each member of the list.

Tags are associated with members of a list and not the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the Mailchimp API endpoint to retrieve all members with a specific tag.

We can loop through all Members on a List, and see what tags each of Member has, as @MailchimpGuy suggested. But this is not ideal if the List contains 10K+ users.

I'm going to attempt to create segment, their sole purpose is for identify Members with a specific tag, then try [List members in segment](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-segment-members/list-members-in-segment/) endpoint.